# Quartz Cron trigger to run every 2nd day

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I want to make my cron execute job every 2nd day. So if i execute job at 25th May, it will run at 25th, 27th, 29th, 31th, 2nd June, 4th June ..

but the issue is, after the end of 31th May, the cron will reset and start running at 1st June, 3rd June, 5th June ... instead of 2nd June, 4th June ..

below is my code..

```
CronTrigger cronTrigger = newTrigger()
      .withIdentity("trigger1", "testJob")
      .startAt(startDate)
      .withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule( * * * 1/2 * ?")
          .withMisfireHandlingInstructionDoNothing())
      .build();
```

Comment: what about "* * * */2 * ?"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```java
CronTrigger cronTrigger = newTrigger()
    .withIdentity("trigger1", "testJob")
    .startAt(startDate)
    .withSchedule(
         CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule(" * * * */2 * ?")
             .withMisfireHandlingInstructionDoNothing()
    ).build();
```

So you need to replace `1/2` with `*/2`. Here `*` means *each day* and `*/2` mean every second day.

---

### UPDATE

`CronTrigger` can not be use to run every 2 days interval as it will always start at 1st day of every month even though last jab execution was on 31, it will run at 1st day of month instead if 2nd day of month. You can set it in to **run after 48 hours in place of every 2 days**.

Please look if this will help you:

```java
trigger = newTrigger()
    .withIdentity("trigger3", "group1")
    .startAt(tomorrowAt(15, 0, 0)  // first fire time 15:00:00 tomorrow
    .withSchedule(
        simpleSchedule()
            .withIntervalInHours(2 * 24) // interval is actually set at 48 hours' worth of milliseconds
            .repeatForever()
    ).build();
```

for more information please refer [This](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.1.x/cookbook/BiDailyTrigger) link

Comment: The expression suggested by Sanjay 
(which is this: '* * * 1/2 * ? *') has the same problem as the one I 
already tried - the schedule will run on December 31st, and then again 
on January 1st.

Comment: i try to run with "0 0 15 1/2 * ? *" and after 31th, it will again running at 1st of new month

Comment: you can try to set time interval as 48hous in place of every 2 days.

Comment: Thanks Sanjay, you are correct, i cant use cron trigger for this, i have to use simple trigger. like you have prescribe at you update.

Answer (score 2):

From [quartz cron](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.1.x/cookbook/BiDailyTrigger) site, i just found out i cannot use cronTrigger to setup every 2nd day job execution.

"At first glance, you may be tempted to use a CronTrigger. However, if this is truly
to be     every two days, CronTrigger won't work. To illustrate this, simply think 
of how   many days are in a typical month (28-31). A cron expression like "0 0 5 2/2 * ?"
would give us a trigger that would restart its count at the beginning of every month. 
This means that we would would get subsequent firings on July 30 and August 2, which is
an interval of three days, not two."